# Keyboard does not work or light up

Tags: mac, keyboard, trackpad

MacBook Air 1534 12” 2016

Accidentally sparked trackpad.
Trackpad and keyboard no longer worked.

Replaced trackpad.
Trackpad now works but keyboard does not.

Could these two flex cables be the culprit?821-2697-A (Keyboard Backlight)
821-00507-03 (IPD)

I notice the trackpad and everything else besides the keyboard work when I disconnect Keyboard backlight flex.

When I disconnect IPD pretty much everything stops working and that’s normal. So this tells me the IPD is not at fault.

Could replacing keyboard backlight flex fix my keyboard problem?

IPD (left)
Keyboard Backlight (right)
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Could these two flex cables be the culprit?821-2697-A (Keyboard Backlight) 821-00507-03 (IPD)

Yes, they *could* be the culprit.

Are they, however?  Who knows.  You have to do proper diagnostics to determine what is wrong.  Simply looking at something is just guessing.

> Could replacing keyboard backlight flex fix my keyboard problem?

Possibly, if it is what's causing the issue.

You have to test the cables - that means checking continuity and resistance on each pin.  It can also be the keyboard controller.  It can be any number of things and only putting hands-on and doing actual diagnostics can you be certain.

It's understandable that you want some more certainty than guessing, but unless it's blatantly obvious like the cable is burnt or cut, nobody can simply look at a picture of an electrical component and tell you proof positive that it's the failure point.  If it were obvious, you wouldn't need to ask.

Comment: This may sound ridiculous, but could it possibly be a ground problem?

Comment: Yes.  If there's a short to ground

Answer (score 0):

So I just connected the cable again and the caps lock turned on and off as if it just made a bit of contact. So this tells me it could just be a loose cable.